# How to skip support/index.js for certain spec files in Cypress

Tags: cypress

Is it possible to skip the `beforeEach` function in my [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io) **index.js** support file, for a certain spec file (access.spec.js)?

**index.js**

```
// This example support/index.js is processed and
// loaded automatically before your test files.

beforeEach(function () {
  cy.request('POST', 'https://exampleURL.com', {
    email: 'email',
    password: 'password'
  }).then((response) => {
    cy.setCookie('accessToken', response.body.AccessToken);
  });

  cy.setCookie('email', 'email');
  cy.setCookie('environment', '3');
  cy.setCookie('name', 'name');
}
```

**access.spec.js**

```
it("it should send user back to login screen when AccessToken is missing", () => {
  // Code here
});
```

Comment: The support file is meant to be run for every single spec. If you want exemptions, better to selectively choose when to use your `beforeEach` on your specs.

Answer (score 1):

From a conventional perspective, a `beforeEach` block in **support/index.js** should only have code that applies to *all* test specs. If logic only pertains to some tests and not to others, it should not be placed in **support/index.js**.

Trying to override how Cypress intends to use **support/index.js** is working against the framework, and not with it.

Subsequently, an alternative to duplicating this `beforeEach` logic in all tests that require it, would be to create a [Custom Command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax), like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  cy.request('POST', 'https://exampleURL.com', {
    email: 'email',
    password: 'password'
  }).then((response) => {
    cy.setCookie('accessToken', response.body.AccessToken);
  });

  cy.setCookie('email', 'email');
  cy.setCookie('environment', '3');
  cy.setCookie('name', 'name');
})
```

...and then, from within the specs that require this functionality, you could have a simpler `beforeEach` block, like this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  cy.login();
});
```

However, given that your **access.spec.js** test is concerned with a missing `accessToken`, you would not use the `beforeEach` block in that particular test.  Instead, copy the login code into that test, and use [`cy.route`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Syntax) instead of [`cy.request`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Syntax) (which hits your actual endpoint), so that you can [stub out](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#With-Stubbing) a response that does not return an `accessToken`.